# insertbefore not working (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, insert

I have searched for various answers on this and can't find them. The examples found here are either completely different, too complex to compare, or just not fitting. I'm sorry if this is a N00bz question, but this just seems to puzzle me.

```
var navElement = document.createElement("div");
navElement.id="nav";
navElement.innerHTML="<ul><li>item1</li><li>item2</li><li>item3</li><li>item4</li></ul>";
var logoElement = getElementById("logo");

logoElement.parentNode.insertBefore(navElement,logoElement);
```

I just want to put one newly created div with the ID "nav" before the other already existent div with the ID "logo", which is in a different already existent div with the ID "content".

I have also tried it once while defining the parent:

```
var navElement = document.createElement("div");
navElement.id="nav";
navElement.innerHTML="<ul><li>item1</li><li>item2</li><li>item3</li><li>item4</li></ul>";

var logoElement = getElementById("logo");
var contentElement = getElementById("content");

contentElement.insertBefore(navElement,logoElement);
```

I don't want alternatives I could use, etc, etc...I would just want a straight-forward answer as to why this isn't working or at least some suggestion what's going wrong here. It's just not showing the #nav in the browser.

Once again, sorry for it being a N00bz question.

Note: On the first one, I checked Firebug, it claims logoElement is undefined for some reason...on the second one, both logoElement and contentElement claim they're undefined.

Edit: Thanks guys! I'm thoroughly embarassed now. :)

Comment: I guess you should call document.getElementById instead of just calling getElementById. The global object is window, not document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logoElement` is undefined because you have not selected it properly.

`getElementById` must be called from `document`:

```
var logoElement = document.getElementById()
```

Comment: also, I would expect an exception when calling `getElementById` without `document.`.

Comment: Whoops! Well that's embarassing.
Works like a charm now. haha! :)
Thanks!

Comment: I recommend you simply delete this question. I don't care about the rep, and it's really too local a problem to help anyone else.